# Change in output for playa:parents inside Stash when going from PHP 5.3.x – 5.4.x

Tags: playa, stash, php

This template works fine on PHP 5.3.x:

```
{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes" conditionals="yes"}

{stash:st_content}

  {exp:channel:entries
    channel="people"
    url_title="{segment_3}"
    dynamic="no"
    disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
  }
    {exp:playa:parents
      channel="projects"
      disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
    }
    …
    {/exp:playa:parents}
  {/exp:channel:entries}

{/stash:st_content}

{/exp:stash:set}
```

but after upgrading to PHP 5.4.x, each project instead outputs the name of the people entry and no other content.

Anyone know why?

EDIT:

It seems that Stash isn't actually to blame here because if I remove Stash tags I get the same thing.

My expected output at a URL like /project/by/persons-name/ would be

- Project A
- Project B

etc. with only projects assigned to that person via the Playa field.

Instead, what I'm getting is

- Person's Name
- Person's Name

etc. for every entry in the projects channel.

The updated template with Stash taken out looks like:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="people"
    url_title="{segment_3}"
    dynamic="no"
    disable="categories|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
  }
    {exp:playa:parents
      channel="projects"
      disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
    }
    …
    {/exp:playa:parents}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Side point but that should be parse_conditionals in the {exp:stash:set}

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely happening due to a parsing conflict between `{exp:channel:entries}` and `{exp:playa:parent}` – the former is parsing your `{title}` tag before Playa can get to it.

The way to solve it is with Playa’s `var_prefix` parameter, which allows you to alias the tags that Playa is supposed be parsing, so that other tags won’t see them.

```
{exp:playa:parents
  channel="projects"
  disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
  var_prefix="project"
}
    {project:title}
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

Comment: I've already tried using the var_prefix, and while that does output the correct data from the projects channel, it still outputs *all* projects for every person, not just the ones that have had the person assigned to it via the Playa field.

Comment: @Tyssen Sorry for the late reply. If you're still experiencing that, please contact support@pixelandtonic.com as it sounds like a bug.